# How to restore build.gradle and .Gradle folder

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I was trying to solve an issue with Android Studio I accidentally deleted .Gradle folder at the top of the project and build.gradle from within the app. I will post a screen shot of my project in Android Studio. The build tab also produces "make module my app project name" and "deploy module to app engine". The usual clean project, rebuild.... are not there.

[image]

How can I restore them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied both from a different project and pasted them in my project. That didn't solve the problem and I imported the project File->new->import project but that only created a duplicate within my project. I closed the project and deleted it from the list of project in Android studio. Then I created a project by importing it from Android Studio Projects folder. It took forever stuck in the gradle build and I have to restart AS manually. Now I have all my files and the project is compiling as it should.

Answer (score 3):

If your are not using a VCS:

- try use the local history to recovery the `build.gradle` file in your root folder (right click on the root folder)
- If it fails. you can create a new project and copy the `build.gradle`. Usually this file contains generic info (like android gradle pluging and the repos to be used in the modules)
- the `.gradle` folder is not a problem. Gradle wrapper will recreate this file

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reimport your project it will by default create the new gradle folder