# Weird Text generating in android

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

i am working on a local project and the build.gradle(project) file has following data generated automatically.

```
Êþº¾   3x
 suv ALT I 
ConstantValue   CTRL  FUNCTION  META  SHIFT  SYM  action0  
action_bar  action_bar_activity_content  action_bar_container    action_bar_root 
 action_bar_spinner  action_bar_subtitle  action_bar_title 
 action_container  action_context_bar  action_divider  action_image  action_menu_divider  action_menu_presenter  action_mode_bar  action_mode_bar_stub  action_mode_close_button  action_text  actions  activ
```

I cannot run the project. Its not in a original gradle format. 
I am using androidx with studio version 3.3.
sometimes it happens with colors.xml and ic_launcher xml files also.

Comment: BTW, it creates weird text in any files (except java) whenever i click on run button of android studio.Stuck here....

Comment: Not sure if you already did but check your auto encoding settings in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In case you tried to delete your gradle files and tried to copy-paste it from somewhere else you'll get to see this kind of thing in gradle you can try this [you can try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293480/11099870). Hope this will work for you. And never ever delete gradle files again.

Comment: @VirajS, in any case, did you moved or copied or transferred your project files?